# How to properly set hash value in Rspec FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm doing a test using RSPEC.
In my model, i have

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :order_hash
   ....
end
```

In my Factory, i have:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
 factory :user do
   ....
   order_hash { {"id"=>389700649004, "email"=>"test@gmail.com"} }
 end
end
```

But my problem parsing/using the values after save is that it became:

```
User.first.order_hash returns:

{"table"=>{"id"=>505311428702, "email"=>"croska2012@gmail.com"}}

What I need is: {"id"=>505311428702, "email"=>"croska2012@gmail.com"}
```

How can I save the values **without** `"table"=>`, i need only the data hash as i set in Factory.
I tried to add `.to_hash` but doesn't worked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What data type is the order_hash in your db?

Comment: @SebastianPalma :text

Comment: It could be something in your test? Or something in the model (e.g. `before_save`, or an overridden `User#order_hash` method?) Or some module/base class/gem that alters the behaviour? Without a [mcve] of the problem, I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: @TomLord you're right, since I used OpenStruct to use data as (.id, .email etc) then when the code converts it to json, that's when the {"table" => {}} was generated.
Still figuring out how to remove it.

Comment: @aldrien.h If you share the implementation - i.e. provide a [mcve] - I'd be happy to help. But without knowing what you've done with `OpenStruct`, I can only make vague guesses to the solution.

Comment: Hi @TomLord if i have something like,  {:id=>1, :codes=>[{'test'=> 1}, {'test'=>2}]}
how can i convert it to OpenStuct Object, even hashes inside the Array. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how that relates to your error, sorry. I need to see a [mcve].  How can I _reproduce_ the error? Where does the `table` come from?